# Bluetooth Fatal Exception Main android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

For some reason, this new bluetooth code causes my application to "Stop working" and crash. When ever I get an error like this I suspect it is the Android Manifest. However, I cannot find any issues with it. Please focus your attention to the bluetooth code, located in the start function. The code without it works without crashing the application. My format is quite noobish also.

Main Activity.java

```
package com.example.real;



import java.util.Set;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
    Button start, stop;
    TextView tv;
    TextView tv2;
    TextView sum;
    LocationManager lm;
    TextToSpeech Talker;
    Intent phone = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    String Hello = ("Hello World");
    int i,sum1;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Initilize Test Function Hello World
        Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) 
           {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "GPS in Progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
         }); 

        //Initialize Counter Sequence
        start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);// Launch Seizure Sequence
        stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);//Override Function
        tv  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText("30"); // starting from 30.
        sum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sum);

        final MyCounter timer = new MyCounter(30000,1000);
        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
                {
                for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
                {
                    if(device.getName().equals("uIceblue2")) 
                    {
                        mmDevice = device;
                        for(i=0;i<100;i++)
                            {
                                sum1 = sum1 + i;
                                sum.setText("Sum:"+sum1);
                                if(sum1 > 120)
                                    {
                                    timer.start();
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        });
        stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timer.cancel();
                tv.setText("Emergency Call to first responders prevented");
            }
        });
        //Initialize GPS layout
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GPS);
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 20, 1, this);
    }
       public class MyCounter extends CountDownTimer{

            public MyCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
                super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                System.out.println("Timer Completed.");
                tv.setText("Sending information to first responders.");


                phone.setData(Uri.parse("tel:7034004407"));
                startActivity(phone);

            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tv.setText((millisUntilFinished/1000)+"");
                System.out.println("Timer  : " + (millisUntilFinished/1000));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) 
        {
            String lat = String.valueOf(arg0.getLatitude());
            String lon = String.valueOf(arg0.getLongitude());
            Log.e("GPS", "location changed: lat="+lat+", lon="+lon);
            tv2.setText("lat="+lat+", long="+lon);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            Log.e("GPS", "provider disabled " + arg0);
        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            Log.e("GPS", "provider enabled " + arg0);
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            Log.e("GPS", "status changed to " + arg0 + " [" + arg1 + "]");
        }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.real"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.real.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Error Log

```
10-24 16:58:12.716: E/AndroidRuntime(794): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 16:58:12.716: E/AndroidRuntime(794): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.real/com.example.real.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 16:58:12.716: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
10-24 16:58:12.716: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-24 16:58:12.716: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-24 16:58:12.716: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-24 16:58:12.716: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-24 16:58:12.716: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 16:58:12.716: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-24 16:58:12.716: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 16:58:12.716: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-24 16:58:12.716: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-24 16:58:12.716: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-24 16:58:12.716: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-24 16:58:12.716: E/AndroidRuntime(794): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 16:58:12.716: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at com.example.real.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:124)
10-24 16:58:12.716: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-24 16:58:12.716: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
10-24 16:58:12.716: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
10-24 16:58:12.716: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
10-24 16:58:12.716: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  ... 11 more
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is your trying to use mBluetoothAdapter to construct a member variable.

```
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;   //mBluetoothAdapter is null.
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Hey I'm a noob, but would that mean I need to put it those lines of code in the actual Onclick (View V method).

Comment: Well that or you could just intialize the BluetoothAdapter to be BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();  instead of null.  however I wouldn't do either of those on object construction vs onCreate or in an independent thread (depending on what your doing).